# can anyone help me how to hook java.net.Socket.connect(java.net.SocketAddress, int) with frida on an Android device

Tags: android, frida

I want to use Frida to hook java.net.Socket.connect() method in an android application. But I failed, the application crashed.

I am using a Nexus 6 device with Android 7.1.1 and frida-server-12.2.27-android-arm.

Here is the js code I used:

```py
jscode = """
Java.perform(function(){
   var target = Java.use("java.net.Socket");

   target.$init.overload().implementation = function(){
       return this.$init();
   };

   target.connect.overload('java.net.SocketAddress', 'int').implementation = function(socketAddr, timeout) {
   this.connect(socketAddr, timeout);
   };
});
"""
```

I find out that if I just hook $init() method, it all does well; But if I add the hook of method connect(), the APP will crash.

Comment: Add crash/error log

Comment: I changed my device OS from Android 7.1.1 factory image to my own compiled Android.  It's Ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add return in function `connect` body. I tried ,it works.

```
jscode = """
Java.perform(function(){
   var target = Java.use("java.net.Socket");

   target.$init.overload().implementation = function(){
       return this.$init();
   };

   target.connect.overload('java.net.SocketAddress', 'int').implementation = function(socketAddr, timeout) {
   return  this.connect(socketAddr, timeout);
   };
});
"""
```